# Recursive Algorithm into Iterative

Tags: algorithm, recursion, iteration

How can I turn the following recursive algorithm into an iterative algorithm?

```
count(integer: n)
  for i = 1...n
    return count(n-i) + count(n-i)
  return 1
```

Essentially this algorithm computes the following:

```
count(n-1) + count(n-2) + ... + count(1)
```

Comment: `count (integer: n) return 2^n-1`

Comment: I should clarify, without using 2^n-1

Comment: This is not a tail recursion algorithm, so transforming it to iteration, while possible, is not trivial.

Comment: `1<<n - 1` is the same as `2^n - 1` and "doesn't use `2^n -1`"

Comment: That algo goes not make sense. You return from the first iteration of aloop. Should this be `if n > 1` instead of `for i to n`?

Comment: I think you meant 
    
    return count(n-i) + count(n)

Comment: @tobias_k It works perfectly, because `for i to n` for `n==1` will not enter the loop's body, and will skip to `return 1`. (I am assuming iteration starts from 1 here, since this is pascal like syntax)

Comment: @jmugz3 I think you meant `n + count(n-i)`

Comment: your pseudocode is not well specified. Could you review it? The for loop is incorrect and the return statement will only work once

Comment: @mtk99 It makes perfect sense. The loop is perfectly fine (when realizing it's pascal-like pseudo code), and the `return 1` statement is the base clause, which is called when `n==0`.

Comment: @amit: mmm... So if I call count(3), how many times does return get executed? what do I get back?

Comment: Always "opening" the left term: `count(3) = count(2) + count(1) + count(0) = count(1) + count(0) + count(1) + count(0) = count(0) + count(0) + count(1) + count(0) = 1 + count(0) + count(1) + count(0) = 1 + 1 + count(1) + count(0) = 1 + 1 + count(0) + count(0) = 1 + 1 + 1 + count(0) = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4 = 2^(3-1)`

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. There is no use for the for loop. if would be the same "if n==0 return 1 else return count(n-1)+count(n-1)"

Comment: @mtk99 you're right. I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. So how would you turn that into an iterative algorithm?

Comment: @J.Wells, can you correct your pseudocode? Is it `for i 1:n`, or `for i:1 to(n-1)`? If it is former, you would get `2^n`, if latter, you'd get `2^(n-1)`. @amit seems to assume the latter in his excellent analysis, however, we need to be sure if that's right.

Comment: @J.Wells. That would be my proposed answer

Comment: @mtk99 thank you! I've got it now. That worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define your problem in the following recursive way:

```
count(integer : n)
    if n==0 return 1 
    return count(n-1)+count(n-1)
```

Converting to an iterative algorithm is a typical application of backwards induction where you should keep all previous results:

```
count(integer : n):
  result[0] = 1

  for i = 1..n
     result[i] = result[i-1] + result[i-1]

  return result[n]
```

Ir is clear that this is more complicated than it should be because the point is to exemplify backwards induction. I could be accumulating into a single place but I wanted to provide a more general concept that could be extended to other cases. In my opinion the idea is clearer this way.

The pseudocode can be improved after the key idea is clear. In fact, there are two very simple improvements that are applicable only to this specific case:

- instead of keeping all previous values, only the last one is necessary
- there is no need for two identical calls as there are no side-effects expected

Going beyond, it is possible to calculate that based on the definition of the function, count(n)= 2^n

Answer (score 1):

This is not a tail recursion, so it is not trivial to transform it into iterative.

However, a recursion can be simulated using a stack and loop pretty easily, by pushing to the stack rather than recursing.

```
stack = Stack()
stack.push(n)
count = 0
while (stack.empty() == false):
  current = stack.pop()
  count++
  for i from current-1 to 1 inclusive (and descending):
     stack.push(i)
return count
```

---

Another solution is doing it with [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), since you don't need to calculate the same thing multiple times:

```
DP = new int[n+1]
DP[0] = 1
for i from 1 to n:
  DP[i] = 0
  for j from 0 to i-1:
    DP[i] += DP[j]
return DP[n]
```

Note that you can even optimize it to run in `O(n)` rather than `O(n^2)`, by remembering the "so far sum":

```
sum = 1
current = 1
for i from 1 to n:
  current = sum
  sum = sum + current
return current
```

---

Lastly, this actually sums to something you can easily pre-calculate: `count(n) = 2^(n-1), count(0) = 1` (You can suspect it from seeing the last iterative solution we have...)

base: `count(0)` automatically yields 1, as the loop's body is not reached.

Hypothesis: `T(k) = 2^(k-1)` for all `k < n`

Proof:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + ... + T(1) + T(0) = (induction hypothesis)
     = 2^(n-2) + 2^(n-3) + ... + 2^0 + 1 = 
     = sum { 2^i | i=0,...,n-2 } + 1 = (sum of geometric series)
     = (1-2^(n-1)/(1-2)) + 1 =  (2^(n-1) - 1) + 1 = 2^(n-1)
```

Comment: There is something strange in the proof: You replace T(0)=1 but T(n)=2^(n-1) if that were the case then T(0)=2^(0-1)=1/2. Right?

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer. The OP seems to be confused about what he wants!

Comment: @mtk99 The answer explicitly says `T(0)=1, T(n)=2^(n-1) n>0`. As intuition, it does not make sense to have non integer values. The proof uses exactly this assumption, and shows correctness.

Comment: @amit If you look at the OP's code, you will see that T(1)=2. What he later says about what is being calculated it is not correct. The proof is not applicable to his piece of code.

Answer (score -1):

The statement `return count(n-i) + count(n-i)` appears to be equivalent to `return 2 * count(n-i)`.  In that case:

```
count(integer: n)
  result = 1
  for i = 1...n
    result = 2 * result
  return result
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Wow! You mean instead of making 2 recursive calls and return the sum of their return values, we do one recursive call and return the double of its return value? How are they equivalent?

Comment: @KedarMhaswade Unless `f()` is stateful, when are `f(x) + f(x)` and `2 * f(x)` **not** arithmetically equivalent?  Please show a counter-example, I'd be fascinated!

Comment: You are right, @pjs. I just missed the `return`! I must have been overly multitasking :( -- apologies.